# Склонение иностранной женской фамилии Саава, заканчивающейся на безударную -а?

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Склоняется ли женская фамилия Саава?

Answer (score 1):

Мужские и женские фамилии и личные имена, оканчивающиеся на -а, -я неударное, склоняются независимо от их языковой принадлежности (в том числе и к грузинскому, японскому, финскому языкам).

Склонение фамилии Саава по образцу сущ. 1-го склонения.

http://studall.org/all-39601.html

Comment: Речь идет о безударном окончании А.